# Is there a way to solve import issues with __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, python-import

I have a package with this structure

```
framework/
    __init__.py
    file0.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
```

I want to able to import it as `import framework`, but I'm not able to do it that way, only `from framework import *` works, and that too without autocomplete. `file0.py` and `file1.py` are classes, and the others have only functions.
Autocomplete works, however, when I manually do this on the file I'm working on in an external directory

```
from framework import file0
from file0 import *
# and so on for the others
```

This is my `__init.py__`

```
from framework.file0 import file0
from framework.file1 import file1
from framework.file2 import *
from framework.file3 import *
```

I've tried putting

```
from framework import file0
from file0 import *
# and so on for the others
```

on `__init.py__` but it doesn't solve the issue, autocomplete still doesn't work unless I put them in the actual file I'm working on in another directory. I want it to able to work on `import framework`
Is there a way?
Thanks in advance. I'm new to this, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you re-indent the structure to make to clearer

Comment: @mkrieger1 my bad, I've edited it

Comment: @CyDevos re-indented

Comment: No, `file0.py` and `file1.py` are not classes. They are *files* that define modules that can *contain* classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want for your `__init__.py` is `from .file0 import file0`, or whatever content from `file0.py` you want to import.

See [Package relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) in Python docs.

However, I think it's ill adviced to import everything in a package to `__init__.py`. If you do that, it will be loaded into python every time you try to import anything from that package. Say you want to do `from framework.file0 import SomeClass` into some other package, and that class is all you need from `framework`. If you import everything in `__init__py`, you will be loading all that every time you touch that package, since `__init__.py` is always loaded when accessing the package.

If you want a way to import everything from the package, maybe you should put that in another file, say `all.py`, and then do `from framework import all as framework`?

Comment: ```from .file0 import file0``` gives ```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```. I'm not sure what's causing the issue

Comment: I think that happens if you're in the project root directory, which is not a package per se. It's a module. Subdirectories with an `__init__.py` is a package. You can only use relative imports in packages. Try without the dot, i.e. `from file0 import *`.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, `__init__.py` is to be left blank.

Then in the script file where you need to import the complete package (with all  the files), put this at the top and you should be good to go.

```
import framework
```

And if you want to import only one module for some reason, say `framework.file0`, you can use

```
import framework.file0
```

As far as autocompletion is concerned, this approach worked for me, in JupyterLab Notebook as well as the console.

Comment: I want to able to import all those files, they'll all be in use

Comment: The point here being it works, but importing all those files might be a burden everytime

Comment: Using `import framework ` imports everything in the framework directory. To access the individual modules you will be using `framework.file0` instance in your code like any other standard package.

Comment: The `import framework.file0` was just an example should you want to use only one module.